# Are there any new Eclipse distributions?

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I've been using EasyEclispe for a long time, and I've noticed that they haven't really kept up-to-date with the main Eclipse distro.  So I was wondering if anybody knew of an EasyEclipse-like distribution that would contain common things people in different areas of Java/Groovy development might need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the [eclipse download site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and click on member distros.  There are a bunch of different groupings of plugins for different peoples needs. One of those is Yaxos.  The [Yaxos on-demand](http://yoxos.com/ondemand/) site lets you configure your plugins prior to download.  They have groovy monkey in there.

Comment: That Yaxos on-demand thing is boss!  It's exactly what I need.  It's almost like running an installer on an OS and the OS asking you what it needs.

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer to just install the latest "real" Eclipse (Ganymede) and use its inbuilt tools to install and keep up-to-date all the different plugins and features I use.

That way, it never drops behind the mainstream release and I don't have to pay any money to companies that are really just repackaging what I can get for free.

This cost is especially important since MyEclipse is per-seat licensing which can get expensive very fast. I'm not even sure why people would choose to use it. The only thing it seems to offer over baseline Eclipse is tutorials and support, of which there are a plethora on the internet without having to shell out money.

As for EasyEclipse, at least it's free and it provides more pre-packaged Eclipse variants than Eclipse itself but it's really not that difficult to get everything you need from within Eclipse by looking through [Epic](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care if it's free or commercial, I've been using [MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/) for a long time.  I find the price reasonable and the feature set nice.  I think this is one of the bigger commercial distributions of Eclipse plus many plugins.

You can see the advertised feature set of MyEclipse [here](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-1.html).  Note that the significantly more expensive "Blue" edition is specifically for WebSphere development.  I have not used this and cannot comment on it.

Comment: I've used that before, although it was a long time ago, when we had it we only used it to quickly deploy class changes to the container.  Does it do more now?

Comment: Just added a link to features in my answer.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **http://www.springsource.com/products/sts** from springsource (groovy inside)